# How to Encode Special Character in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

How to encode special chaacters in pandas.

my_csv:

```
column A
Id - Number
Id – Column

my_df = pd.read_csv('my_csv.csv', encoding = 'latin-1')
```

my_df

```
Id - Number
Id ? Column
```

In my csv there is one column i.e, column A which has two values, when i am reading this file in pandas my second value becomes something like below. How can i read my second value as it is in the csv.

```
Id - Number  --> Id - Number
Id – Column  --> Id ? Column  --> it should be like Id – Column
```

Comment: are you sure it is `latin-1`?

Comment: do you use Windows? Do you run in console? Maybe problem is not dataframe but console can't display it. As I kno Windows console may use `cp1250` to display text and it can make problem.

Comment: yes, i use windows. encoding = 'cp1252' solves my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character `–` (U+2013) *En Dash* is defined in most 8-bit Windows code pages as `'\x96'`.

Unfortunately, in `'iso-8859-1'` (or `'latin-1'` if you want), this character is U+0096 *Start Of Guarded Area* (a non-printable character; hence the question mark as a replacement character).

Use

```
import pandas as pd
my_df = pd.read_csv('my_csv.csv', encoding = 'cp1252')
my_df
```

> ```
>       column A
> 0  Id - Number
> 1  Id – Column
> ```